# nmbd error: Answer name differs from question name

Tags: server, 20.04, samba

On 3/8/23 my systems received an update for samba. As soon as the samba server restarted after the update, nmbd started spamming the syslog with hundreds of error messages a day, none of which had been emitted in the prior years that this server had been running samba.

The log entries look like this, with only the "question and answer name" varying between entries

```
Apr  5 00:55:35 [servername] nmbd[710482]: [2023/04/05 00:55:35.886107,  0] ../../source3/nmbd/nmbd_nameregister.c:73(register_name_response)
Apr  5 00:55:35 [servername] nmbd[710482]:   register_name_response: Answer name  <00> differs from question name <00>.
```

I wrote a launchpad [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/2011583) but I only got a rather generic "stuff happens sometimes" response:

> This new version may have become more picky or verbose in some cases.

I have not been able to find any information online about what these error messages actually mean or what the implications  of them them are.

Does anyone know what causes nmbd to emit these error messages? Or even what these "questions" and "answers" are?

Comment: I do not have that issue on any of my many machines running Samba but I had removed the netbios info from the samba config. https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/nmbd.8.html